# Assistance with MYSQL_OPT_SSL_MODE

Tags: c++, mysql

I just started messing around with this and not entirely sure how to pass "SSL_Mode_DISABLED" as a valid statement when the argument appears to be expecting an int.

I'm trying to add the second line so that it's valid.

```
mysql_options(&self->handle, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
mysql_options(&self->handle, MYSQL_OPT_SSL_MODE, SSL_MODE_DISABLED);
```

> MYSQL_OPT_SSL_MODE (argument type: unsigned int *)
>
> The security state to use for the connection to the server:
> SSL_MODE_DISABLED , SSL_MODE_PREFERRED, SSL_MODE_REQUIRED,
> SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA, SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY. If this option is not
> specified, the default is SSL_MODE_PREFERRED. These modes are the
> permitted values of the mysql_ssl_mode enumeration defined in mysql.h.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to find simple practical examples that worked.

After a little trial and error, the following seems to be working for me.

```
uint opt_use_ssl = SSL_MODE_DISABLED;           
mysql_options(&self->handle, MYSQL_OPT_SSL_MODE, (uint const*) &opt_use_ssl);
```